# JQuery select change in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages...

main.php and inside that page I have an iframed page subpage.php

Inside subpage.php I have the following jquery:

```
$('#month').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
});
```

For some reason I'm not getting any alerts.

Does the code have to be different in iframes?

How can I get this working?

Comment: Does your code run without errors? Is it being triggered? Use the debug console (F12 in most browsers)

Comment: Checked the console but no errors in that department...it's just not triggering the alert

Comment: That script may run before the DOM is ready. Did you put it at the very end of the body or inside a `ready` handler?

Comment: I put it inside a ready handler as there's no body tags in the iframed page.

Comment: Does it work when you load the iframe URL directly in your browser, rather than as an iframe? Also what Browser are you using - have you tried it in a few different browsers?

Comment: I may be completely wrong, but do you need to have jQuery referenced in the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#iframe").on('load', function() {
    $("#iframe").contents().find("#month").on('change', function() {
        alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
    });
});
```

It probably didn't work before because the iframe wasn't done loading.

Comment: Tried it ... $("#calframe").contents().find("#month").on('change', function() {
   alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
});  ... but still no alert.

Comment: No, still no alerts happening. strange :/

Comment: I don't know if this helps but for some reason this: 
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
 {
    
 alert('TEST');  ... etc won't work either

Comment: Put the JavaScript inside the main page, not iframe.

Comment: I've tested this code on a local test site, and it did work for me. I don't know why it's not working for you.